# Data Vault 2.0 - What is a multi-active satellite?

Tags: database, database-design, data-vault

My question is about the *Data Vault 2.0 methodology* for data modeling.

-------**What is a multi-active satellite?**-------

I could not find a very basic definition with a very basic example for it in any book or website.

Comment: I actually just found this example **https://danlinstedt.com/allposts/datavaultcat/reviewing-multi-active-satellites/**, don't know why I haven't come across it earlier. It also seems alright.

Answer (score 0):

A coworker provided me a very basic and easy-to-understand definition: the phone number example for a multi active satellite.

We have **a "Person" Hub** and **a multi-active "PhoneNumber" satellite** connected to it. In the PhoneNumber satellite, there is a home and work phone number for each person. The home phone number may not change for 17 years, but the work phone number may change e.g. every two years.

**The multi-active satellite preserves "multi-active history" for both phone numbers,** for every person in the Person Hub.

*Please correct me if I have understood this example wrong!*

Comment: I think you get it wrong. With classical DV approach in this specific case, you have two hubs - **Person** and **PhoneNumber** and ref **PhoneRole**. Two Hubs and Ref are connected with a link, its satellite define the PhoneNumber.